# Significato di "sotto l'ala del mercato" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel racconto *La sposa bambina* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Catinina del Freddo era di quella razza che da noi si marchia col nome di mezzi zingari perché mezza la loro vita la passano **sotto l’ala del mercato**. 
>         Proprio **sotto l’ala** si trovava, a tredici anni giusti, a giocare coi maschi a tocco e spanna, quando sua madre le fece una chiamata straordinaria.

Il significato di "tocco e spanna" l'ho trovato spiegato su [questo esame di maturità](https://www.sbfi.admin.ch/dam/sbfi/it/dokumente/italiano.6.pdf.download.pdf/italiano.pdf):

> gioco che consiste nel far avvicinare di una spanna la propria bilia a quella dell'avversario.

Non riesco a capire, però, il significato dell'espressione "sotto l'ala" in questo passaggio. Me lo potreste spiegare? Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ala) e sul [dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/A/ala.shtml) ho trovato che "essere (o mettersi) sotto l'ala (o le ale) di qualcuno" significa "affidarsi alla protezione di qualcuno, godere della protezione di qualcuno". Tuttavia, non sono sicura che questo abbia senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato: cosa vorrebbe dire "essere sotto la protezione del mercato"? Significherebbe "protezione" in senso fisico, cioè, per esempio, dare riparo dalla pioggia?

Comment: Penso si riferisca ad una struttura architettonica. Ala: *Prolungamento laterale di una struttura edilizia o muraria: l'a. destra di un edificio.* https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/ala.shtml - “*Similmente ad altri insediamenti dell’area, l’ala del mercato occupa una porzione del principale spazio urbano del paese, sul quale si affacciano talvolta anche gli edifici del potere civico, quali il municipio, e/o della fede, quali la chiesa parrocchiale.*” https://comune.osasco.to.it/contenuti/60887/ala-mercato

Comment: @Gio: Non capisco cosa sia questa "ala del mercato" di Osasco.

Comment: È solo un esempio di “ala di mercato” in senso architettonico. Ne trovi molte altre in rete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un [articolo](https://www.massimobattaglio.it/2017/10/16/le-ale-dei-mercati-in-piemonte/) descrive le *ali di mercato* in Piemonte, particolari tipologie di edifici, di solito rettangolari, coperte, usate per i commerci:

> Si tratta di quelle tettoie solitamente rettangolari e contornate da archi o pilastri, che si vedono nei centri storici, sotto le quali, quasi sempre, si svolge ancora oggi qualche attività di commercio ambulante.

Immagino che la copertura sia stata pensata per proteggere merci e persone dal maltempo.

Il più delle volte, sotto la tettoia delle ali dei mercati si sistemavano degli ambulanti con le loro merci. È probabile che nel testo si faccia riferimento proprio agli ambulanti (uomini o donne che vendono oggetti spostandosi di città in città, di paese in paese, senza dunque possedere un negozio) citando gli «zingari».

Comment: Potresti aggiungere qualche dettaglio in più su cosa fossero queste "ali di mercato"?  Penso sia importante per poter capire come qualcuno si potesse trovare sotto una di queste ali, che è quello che si chiede nella domanda.

Comment: Le aggiunte possono andare bene? (Forse la domanda potrebbe essere completata con «del mercato»: “sotto l’ala del mercato”)

Comment: Ottimo, @Benedetta! Ti sembrano bene le mie aggiunte al tuo post?

Comment: Va bene, @Charo. Una piccola cosa: nella citazione: pilasti > pilastri.

Answer (score 1):

Nella risposta data sopra, come nelle pubblicazioni del Politecnico di Torino, si sta confondendo la parola italiana "l'ala/le ali" di un edificio, che ha il plurale in -i, con una parola piemontese (non italiana), "l'ala/le ale", che ha il plurale in -e.

I due termini hanno non solo significato, ma anche origine completamente differente:

1. quello italiano ha una origine latina da "ala", parte del corpo di un volatile. Le ali di un edificio si paragonano a quelle di un uccello.
2. la parola piemontese ha origine germanica, identica a quella del francese "halle" e dell'inglese "hall". Non è "halla" solo perché il piemontese non ha mai avuto aspirate e non è "alla" perché non ha doppie.

Quindi, quando si parla di tettoie mercatali piemontesi, bisogna dire "le ale" e non "le ali".

Comment: Molto interessante, grazie. Potresti aggiungere una fonte (un dizionario o una grammatica piemontese, per esempio)?

Comment: Il link (purtroppo ora non più funzionante) dice “le-ale-dei-mercati” e credo non ci sia alcuna confusione. È interessante però scoprire l'origine del termine.

Comment: L'articolo parla di "ale", ma la risposta in cui si trova il link al medesimo parla di "ali" del mercato, quindi erra.

Comment: D'altra parte anche in italiano antico esisteva "alla" con il significato di tettoia del mercato
Basta cercare in
http://tlio.ovi.cnr.it/TLIO/

Comment: https://books.google.it/books?id=JNFFAAAAcAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA35&vq=ala&dq=dizionario+piemontese+italiano&hl=it&output=html&source=gbs_search_r&cad=1